# Is it correct to use Lombok in a domain object?

Tags: java, architecture, enterprise-architecture

I'm starting the refactoring of a legacy app in favor of having a more organized structure, I chose to go with hexagonal architecture since I have lots of well-defined ports and adapters, my use cases are clear as well as the domain. One of the things I found in this legacy is the usage of lombok almost everywhere, when the theory clearly states that the domain models should remain clean from external dependencies (pure java code that can be moved everywhere), and this enters into a small contradiction with what it's done. My question is, is it correct to use Lombok in my domain objects or should I fully scaffold the class, I do read-only classes so getters is the only thing I put there but still looks verbose.

Thank you for the answer in advanced.

Comment: **It is never correct to use Lombok**. *If* you feel it would help, it's because you are probably doing procedural programming and anemic "objects", i.e. data structures. In any case Lombok is *never* the solution. It is more or less an indicator that things are bad.

Comment: Got it, as I can see here Lombok is being used in the codebase only for value objects and DTOs, what created the doubt was that they are also using it in the representational models for the domain, but never in a domain service and even less in the infrastructure, but yeah, I'll keep it into account, thanks a lot for the answer @RobertBräutigam.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam i have to disagree. If OPs domain objects are in any way, shape or form, tied to persistence (be it an O/R Mapper or serialization), real OO concepts cease to be applicable; and without real OO lombok can make a lot of sense.
If the domain objects really only exist in-memory then i'd agree that lombok is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @marstato "If OPs domain objects are ... tied to persistence ..., real OO concepts cease to be applicable." I think you were just not exposed to a proper solution in this regard, therefore don't have an example of how oo code looks like. Don't get me wrong, I was the same way. There are hardly any frameworks or libraries out there that would support "real" OO persistence. That doesn't mean oo concepts are not applicable though.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam i firmly believe that the problem here is not my (or anyone elses) experience. OO is about behaviour and hiding internal state. Persistence is purely about state and not about behaviour because behaviour cannot be persisted. The two concepts clash at their core. Persistence needs to look deep into the objects internals and OO tries to hide exactly that

Comment: @marstato No, "persistence" does *not* need to look deep into objects. You are just using some *library* that is made that way. Objects are perfectly capable of doing their behavior in a persistent way if they want to. Again, it's just the tools and designs we use that are made to "look deep into the objects internals". And I agree with you that conflicts with OO very much.

Comment: @Robert Brautigam alternatively Lombok can be a sign your trying to do functional programming rather than OOP, and should really just use a language that provides those constructs natively like kotlin or scala. (Eg Lombok is really useful when trying to use Apache spark from java)

Comment: @user1937198 Being able to define data structures and lambda expressions does not an FP language make. When you can write functions without side-effects, have higher kinded types, maybe typeclasses and some support for monadic composition, then and only then can you start to invoke FP. Until then it is all just an excuse.

Comment: Look into records in the latest version of Java.  This will most likely be the primary motivator to migrate beyond Java 11 for developers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lombok is reflecting that Java is limited in it's ability to model a domain and the reality of systems where there is data and there is code. Separate.

Oracle is delivering "records" in JDK 16 (https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/16/, https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) which reflects, I think, that Lombok is serving a need. JEP-395 (records) provides what Lombok does, e.g. `record Point(int x, int y) { }` has getters, hashCode, equals, toString. All in 1 line. A huge improvement. Better than Lombok because it's built into the language and is therefore *portable*.

Java is weak at domain modelling. Perhaps you have the freedom to mix in some Kotlin? Kotlin has records in the language, solves the null/optional issue, choice types, etc.

Perhaps it's worth reflecting upon if OOP is giving you much apart from comfort? After 20 odd years doing OOP (C++ and Java) I'm now rapidly going off it in favour of Kotlin and a much more functional approach; I think OOP is not fit-for-purpose. A side-project has been rewritten in functional Kotlin and I'm finding very little use for classes.

**Update Feb-2023**: I still really like Java records (sealed records are awesome, as will be pattern matching when it finally arrives), but they do have limitations I wasn't originally aware of: -

1. JPA/Hibernate; there are no setters as records are immutable, so they don't play nicely with JPA.
2. There is no "builder" for them; it's all or nothing construction unlike Lombok that has @Builder. Oracle are investigating a better solution for records using the "wither" pattern (https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2022-June/003461.html).

Comment: This is actually a good answer, thanks a lot for that one :)